# How to find rowindex on dropdownlist change event which is placed in table row

Tags: jquery

Following code retun zero. `ddlType` placed in table row.

```
$("#tblType").on('change', 'select.ddlType', function (event) { 
    alert($(this).index());
});
```

Comment: Are you trying to find the index of the selected option within the `select`, or the index of the closest `tr` in `#tblType`?

Comment: @Rory McCrossan second one:- index of the closest tr in #tblType

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the index of the closest `tr` in the table, try this:

```
$("#tblType").on('change', 'select.ddlType', function (event) { 
    alert($(this).closest('tr').index());
});
```